# When does touch command need the file to exist?

Tags: touch

I've noticed sometimes I touch a file that does not exist at all and after the command, the files get created. However, depending on what directory I'm touching, I get "No such file or directory" error.

For example, If I run `touch foo.txt`, the foo.txt file gets created in my home directory. Instead, if I run `touch /bar/foo.txt`, I get `touch: cannot touch '/bar/foo.txt': No such file or directory`.

What's the logic behind this?
Thanks.

Comment: Does `/bar` directory exist? That's what `touch` complains about.

Comment: A NFS mount gone awry (or similar flakey filesystems) could be another cause.

Answer (score 0):

The `touch` command doesn't need the target file to exist, but it needs the parent directory of the target file to exist. So if you want to run `touch /bar/foo.txt` then you need to make sure that the `/bar/` directory already exists.

The `touch` command (like most command-line programs) also assumes that the path argument that you give it is a relative path. So `touch foo.txt` will create a file in your current working directory. If your current directory happens to be your home directory then `foo.txt` will be created in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting "No such file or directory" error because /bar/foo.txt is looking in root/bar/foo.txt. From your home directory try "bar/foo.txt" (not /bar/foo.txt). Assuming that bar directory exists in your home directory